# Using wininet.dll in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-phone-8

I am looking to set proxy on my windows phone app process by invoking methods on wininet.dll. I achieve this in WinRT app using P/Invoke. Since P/Invoke does not work in WP8.1 silverlight app, after some search I figured out way to do this is to create a Windows Phone Runtime C++ component and wrap calls to wininet.dll inside it. What I am unable to figure out is how do I wrap calls to wininet.dll in the runtime component. Trying to reference dll in the WPRT component fails saying "Could not add reference due to one of following reasons : -Targets higher version of .Net. -Not a .Net assembly. -Not a registered ActiveX control.".

How do i do this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Since P/Invoke does not work in WP8.1 silverlight app` are you sure about that?  I think I remember reading that they added support in either 8 or 8.1.

Comment: Using P/Invoke is supported in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime apps only(not with Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight apps). Although the calls to `DllImpor` compiles, it throws error at runtime in Silverlight apps.